# Serial Port Returning Invalid Data

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, serial-port

I have a weighing machine that is connected to a computer using a serial port. It is a very old machine and we are trying to get the weights off it and save in a database.
The weight returned by the machine has some invalid characters like `?`, and the weight is displayed as `??2?0`, where it should have been `02220`.

I understand it has something to do with encoding as results on a web search suggest. But I can not figure out what exactly am I missing.

Here is my code:

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // This method will be called when there is data waiting in the port buffer
    // Read all the data waiting in the buffer
    // string data = comport.ReadExisting();
    // Display the text to the user in the Rich Text Box
    Log(LogMsgType1.Incoming, s); 
}

public void OpenThisPort()
{
    bool error = false;

    // If the port is open, close it
    if (comport.IsOpen)
    {
        comport.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        comport.BaudRate = int.Parse("1200");
        comport.DataBits = int.Parse("8");
        comport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        comport.Parity = Parity.None;
        comport.PortName = "COM1";
        delStart = 0;
        delLength = 9;
        comport.RtsEnable = true;
        comport.DtrEnable = true;
        comport.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
    }
```

How do I determine exactly which encoding will be applied?
Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried simple ASCII encoding?  Read the data as `byte[]` and examine that. Post it here if you can't solve it.

Comment: did you mean       byte[] Bdata = new byte[comport.BytesToRead];
                
                comport.Read(Bdata, 0, Bdata.Length);

                string s = comport.Encoding.GetString(Bdata);

Comment: NO LUCK with reading it by byte[]

Comment: I recommend using a serial port monitor or at least display each received byte in some debug output (you can use myByte.ToString("x2") to print the actual hex value). Then you can compare the data against some codepages and decide what encoding is required.

Comment: I used several serial port monitors... all are returning garbage.. this shows that the problem is not with my software. However, when i connect the same cable to a DOS based computer (which was previously used to get weight off this weighing machine), the data is showing just fine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may not by the encoding issue but error on hardware.
Try detecting it:

```
    #region comPort_ErrorReceived
    /// <summary>
    /// This method will be called when there's data waiting in the buffer
    ///  and error occured.
    /// DisplayData is a custom method used for logging
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void comPort_ErrorReceived(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialError sr = e.EventType;
        switch (sr)
        {
            case SerialError.Frame:
                DisplayData(newLog, EventLogEntryType.Error, "On port " + comPort.PortName
                    + " the hardware detected a framing error.\n", 45);
                break;
            case SerialError.Overrun:
                DisplayData(newLog, EventLogEntryType.Error, "On port " + comPort.PortName
                    + " a character-buffer overrun has occurred. The next character is lost.\n", 46);
                break;
            case SerialError.RXOver:
                DisplayData(newLog, EventLogEntryType.Error, "On port " + comPort.PortName
                    + " an input buffer overflow has occured. There is either no room in the input buffer,"
                    + " or a character was received after the End-Of-File (EOF) character.\n", 47);
                break;
            case SerialError.RXParity:
                DisplayData(newLog, EventLogEntryType.Error, "On port " + comPort.PortName
                    + " the hardware detected a parity error.\n", 48);
                break;
            case SerialError.TXFull:
                DisplayData(newLog, EventLogEntryType.Error, "On port " + comPort.PortName
                    + " the application tried to transmit a character, but the output buffer was full.\n", 49);
                break;
            default:
                DisplayData(newLog, EventLogEntryType.Error, "On port " + comPort.PortName
                    + " an unknown error occurred.\n", 50);
                break;
        }
    }
```

At first glance it looks like framing error, as part of the data seem to be correct. For starters make sure that your cable is good. Also you may try connecting to your device with some other application, e.g putty.

Also reading your data as bytes may be a good idea (and then you may convert it to hex before displaying). This way you will find out what is actually getting sent.

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
int btr = comPort.BytesToRead;
byte[] comBuffer = new byte[btr];
comPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, btr);
Console.WriteLine(ByteToHex(comBuffer));
}

private string ByteToHex(byte[] comByte)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(comByte.Length * 3);
            foreach (byte data in comByte)
                builder.Append(Convert.ToString(data, 16).PadLeft(2, '0').PadRight(3, ' '));
            return builder.ToString().ToUpper();
        }
```

Comment: I used several serial port monitors... all are returning garbage.. this shows that the problem is not with my software. However, when i connect the same cable to a DOS based computer (which was previously used to get weight off this weighing machine), the data is showing just fine

Comment: are you sure that your serial port settings are correct? Try setting RtsEnable and DtrEnable to false. You can also leave alone the encoding and get data in binary form (here is usefull translator http://home.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/). Are you using RS-232 or something else? Post your data in hex and what it's supposed to be. Are there no ErrorReceived events fired?

Comment: I am working on your solution, will revert back once i have implemented displayData method. Also i shall post the HEX data

Comment: You can use log.WriteEntry method, or simply write it to console output, it will be fastest.

Comment: dear @Arie, I am stilll having difficulties getting the data from the serial port. It is working properly on DOS Based software however, not working with .NET... what shall i do?

Comment: ok It turned out that the serial port settings were incorrect... I double checked it as you suggested , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. 
Try changing DataBits to **7** and Parity to **Parity.Even**, then it should work.